# How to redirect to a page on an error in passport-local

Tags: node.js, passport.js

How to redirect to a cutom page on a (example database) error, and display the message, when using [passport-local](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local). here's the code:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({ 
  passReqToCallback: true 
  }, function( req, username, password, done ) {
    done({error:'mycustomerrormessage'});
  }
));
```

the routing looks like:

```
app.post('/auth/local', passport.authenticate('local', { 
    successRedirect: '/', 
    failureRedirect: '/', 
    failureFlash: true 
}));
```

when the error occurs, the url stay `/auth/local`, with a nasty `[object Object]` content.

if I call

```
done( null, false, { message: "error message"})
```

than passport redirects to `/`, and I can `flash` the message, but how can I set a redirection in case I call the `verify` function with a first not `null` parameter and do something with that error?

Answer (score 0):

based on express documentation, you can configure error handling middleware as following:

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next){
  console.error(err.stack);
  res.send(500, 'Something broke!');
});
```

The four parameter signature indicates that this is an error handling definition.

See http://expressjs.com/guide.html#error-handling